# UIScrollView Gestures

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

i have a UIScrollView inside another UIScrollView. i want to be able to zoom into the selected scrollview if i use pinch-to-zoom, but i want to be able to scroll on the parent scrollview if i use only one finger.

the UI structure of the app looks something like this (indentation level shows subview):

```
MainUIView
>UIButton
>UIScrollView
>>UIScrollView
>>UIScrollView
>>UIScrollView
```

is this possible?

thanks in advanced.

Comment: I think you're over complicating this. You should be able to use a single scroll view to zoom and scroll.

Comment: Doesn't setting `scrollEnabled` to `NO` on inner scrollviews do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

It should be what you can do is set `TAG` to the ScrollViews, and depending upon which scrollView gets selected you should take the action ,in the Delegate Methods